# How to include seconds in datetime format?

Tags: php, datetime

I am developing a bidding system and I want to display the date and time of all the bidders and seconds is included in the format.

I used this LOC `echo date('m/d/Y H:i:s', strtotime($w['postedDate']));`

and it displays this `06/17/2013 17:35:00` which is correct except for the seconds.  The seconds in the database for the particular datetime is .53 not 00.

Comment: please post the date from the database. "s" should be the correct one

Comment: Basic debugging: `var_dump($w['postedDate'], strtotime($w['postedDate']));`.

Comment: It looks like the $w['postedDate'] is missing the seconds, what is the value of that variable?

Comment: I suspect that the seconds are not parsed correctly from `$w['postedDate']`. You mentioned seconds being .53 - the dot would probably make it parse as 1/100ths of a second.

Comment: 6/17/2013 5:35:53 PM - this is the value of the variable on the database

string(19) "Jun 17 2013 5:35PM" int(1371515700) - this is the value  of the "var_dump($w['postedDate'], strtotime($w['postedDate']));"

is there a another method I could use to display the datetime included the seconds of the time?

Comment: i fixed it guys, I used ** CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), c.postedDate, 120) AS                    bidDate** to convert the date while it is being selected then used **date('m/d/Y H:i:s', strtotime($w['bidDate']));** to format it the way I want to. Thank you for suggestions really appreciate it.